# Selected text and making bold apart from first word using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know this is something very simple but I am still new to jQuery, so I'm a little unsure how to approach. I have found a good few solutions with making the first word bold but not what I need.

I want to only make the words bold other than the first word; is this possible?

I.E

Buy This Product

to be

Buy **This Product**

I only have a example from another solution for the first word but not sure how to adjust.

```
$('.homepage-boxes .ty-banner__image-wrapper a').find('.ty-btn_ghost').html(function(i, h){
    return h.replace(/\w+\s/, function(firstWord){
      return '<strong>' + firstWord + '</strong>';
    }); 
 });
```

I have adjusted with the classes I need and the find class but I want to make the text `<strong>` but excluding the first word.

Comment: Before anyone says to make the word wrapped in strong tag i cant, as it takes the banner title from the CMS so i need to adjust with JS on page loads :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. You could use a regex like `/ (.*)/` to match the first space followed by every other character to the end of the string as a sub match:

```js
$('.homepage-boxes .ty-banner__image-wrapper a').find('.ty-btn_ghost').html(function(i, h){
  return h.replace(/ (.*)/, " <strong>$1</strong>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- html structure improvised to match the selectors from the question's JS -->
<div class="homepage-boxes">
  <div class="ty-banner__image-wrapper">
    <a><span class="ty-btn_ghost">Buy This Product</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="ty-banner__image-wrapper">
    <a><span class="ty-btn_ghost">Buy The Other Product</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="ty-banner__image-wrapper">
    <a><span class="ty-btn_ghost">Buy Some Third Product</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that using parentheses in the regex allows you to refer to the matched bit using `$1`, so you can provide the replacement as a string in the second argument to `.replace()` rather than passing a function.

Comment: Worked an absolute treat! thanks @nnnnnn really kind of you!!